# Google plus customise what is shared

Tags: google-plus, share

I have the following code,

```
 <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href+'url={'+window.location.href+'}',
  '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;"><img src="google.png" alt="Share on Google Plus"></a>
```

Which works perfectly. I'm developing a simple game in jquery and html and what I want to do is, once the game is over, allow the player to share their score on google plus. The above will share the page only. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The content shared to Google+ is controlled by the [markup of the page being shared](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/).

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Awesome Game 5000</h1>
  <img itemprop="image" src="{image-url}" />
  <p itemprop="description">Super good score of {score}.</p>
</body>
```

In order to dynamically change the score people share you would have to dynamically change the score based on the url. E.g. `https://example.com/shared/5343` would replace the score on the page with `5343`.